# Columns missing in Filters option in DataView WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to filter my dataview webpart, but the column I want to filter is missing in the Filter option in "SharePoint Designer" !. How can we include the columns in the filters option?

PS: I'm using SharePoint 2013 version.

Answer (score 0):

check this blog, title is saying about the clearing the filter but it will basically give you alternate to filter the column.
http://muzsharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2013/07/clearing-filter-selection-on-dataview.html

Do you know what kind of column missing?

another link for customization:http://muzsharepoint2010.blogspot.com/2013/07/filtering-xslt-list-view-webpart-with.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not getting any columns except the 'Created' column in the filters dropdown. I have a date filter on Created column. Also, need to create some filters for other columns too. i.e. Body, Title etc. But, these columns are not listing in the dropdown!

Comment: did you try the clear filter options?

Comment: I'm not getting the "Add XSLT Filtering" checkbox in filters option.